# merge two files by one column

Tags: unix, merge, annotations

I have two files

```
$ wc -l new_bacteria.txt 
28633861 new_bacteria.txt

$ wc -l allin1_trinity_bacteria_blastx.tsv 
4352 allin1_trinity_bacteria_blastx.tsv

$ head new_bacteria.txt
gi|406035365|ref|ZP_11042729.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035366|ref|ZP_11042730.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035367|ref|ZP_11042731.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035368|ref|ZP_11042732.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035369|ref|ZP_11042733.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035370|ref|ZP_11042734.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035371|ref|ZP_11042735.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035372|ref|ZP_11042736.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035373|ref|ZP_11042737.1| Acinetobacter parvus
gi|406035374|ref|ZP_11042738.1| Acinetobacter parvus

$ head allin1_trinity_bacteria_blastx.tsv

c91_g1_i1   gi|46447089|ref|YP_008454.1|    39.60   101 59  1   306 4   1676    1774    6e-11   68.2
c146_g1_i1  gi|357399595|ref|YP_004911520.1|    39.53   86  47  2   246 4   49  134 5e-06   52.0
c202_g1_i1  gi|508605652|ref|YP_006991274.2|    62.16   37  14  0   154 44  49  85  3e-06   45.4
c202_g1_i1  gi|508605652|ref|YP_006991274.2|    63.16   19  7   0   201 145 33  51  3e-06   27.7
c202_g1_i1  gi|508605652|ref|YP_006991274.2|    76.92   13  3   0   242 204 20  32  3e-06   21.6
c224_g1_i1  gi|395217261|ref|ZP_10401556.1| 72.62   84  23  0   260 9   274 357 6e-38     144
c230_g1_i1  gi|261381445|ref|ZP_05986018.1| 57.50   40  17  0   248 129 57  96  2e-09   45.8
c230_g1_i1  gi|261381445|ref|ZP_05986018.1| 50.00   42  19  1   120 1   101 142 2e-09   41.2
c294_g1_i1  gi|298242911|ref|ZP_06966718.1| 37.33   75  46  1   14  238 814 887 3e-07   56.2
c304_g1_i1  gi|296393792|ref|YP_003658676.1|    42.86   56  32  0   56  223 17  72  6e-06   51.2
```

I want to merge this two files by the second column of allin1_trinity_bacteria_blastx.tsv. And I wish to output a file have same number of lines of the this tsv file since the other file is really big.

This is a easy job in R but since here my annotation file (new_bacteria.txt) is really big. I am thinking about using unix merge. But how can I make the output only contains the columns I want in the tsv file, but not all the liens in the new_bacteria.txt file?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please note that you'll need to be a bit more specific and tell us what you've already tried (and isn't working).

Comment: In R we can do: `t1<-read.table("allin1_trinity_bacteria_blastx.tsv") t2<-read.table("new_bacteria.txt") colnames(t1)[1:2]<-c("id","hit") colnames(t2)<-c("hit","taxa") result<-merge(t1,t2,by="hit",all.x=T)` But here I have a problem with r reading the big new.bacteria.txt in since it has 1.5Gb. So I am thinking if unix can do a easier job.

Comment: I'm not proficient in `R` but it seems to me that you are probably looking for a better way to read the file line by line, and not all at once, if size is your limitation. You would have to do the same thing using any other program, using "Unix" or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking about using unix merge. But how can I make the output
>   only contains the columns I want in the tsv file, but not all the
>   liens in the new_bacteria.txt file?

There is indeed a program named `merge`, but despite the name match with the `merge()` function of R, its purpose (combining separate changes to an original file) is not what you need; you could rather use [`join`](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/). Note that the files must be sorted on the join fields. The example script sorts both files prior to joining; if `new_bacteria.txt` is already sorted, you can use it instead of `sorted.txt`; and if you want to run multiple joins on `allin1_trinity_bacteria_blastx.tsv`, it may be worth it to sort it only once and reuse the `sorted.tsv`.

```
sort -k2b allin1_trinity_bacteria_blastx.tsv >sorted.tsv
sort                        new_bacteria.txt >sorted.txt
join -1 2 sorted.tsv sorted.txt
```