# Merge two multi-column files based on one common column

Tags: unix, awk, merge

I have two tab-separated columns that I want to merge based on a common column.
For example:

**File 1:**

```
abandoning  0   V
abandonment 0   N
abandonments    0   N
abandons    0   V
abducted    0   V
abduction   0   N
```

**File 2:**

```
abandonment
abducted
abduction
abound
abounds
abundance
abundant
accessable
```

I want to merge these files into a third file that has an empty value if the information is not available.

**File 3 (desired result):**

```
abandoning  0   V
abandonment 0   N
abandonments    0   N
abandons    0   V
abducted    0   V
abduction   0   N
abound
abounds
abundance
abundant
accessable
```

I have been looking around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757025/merge-two-files-based-on-one-column-awk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072180/merging-two-files-into-one-based-on-the-first-column) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694948/merge-two-files-by-one-column).
So far, the closest thing that I have seen is this:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2} END {for (i in a) print i a[i]}' OrigFile.txt ToMerge.txt | sort > Merged_Dict.txt
```

However, the results do not include the third column information.
The result that I obtain is:

```
abandoning 0
abandonment 0 
abandonments 0
abandons 0
abducted 0 
abduction 0 
abound 
abounds 
abundance 
abundant 
accessable
```

Any hints as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: check this ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401328/search-and-merge-multiple-files-in-unix/31402354#31402354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, can do this is `awk` but there is a tool for this already if your files are already sorted

```
$ join -a1 -a2 file1 file2

abandoning 0 V
abandonment 0 N
abandonments 0 N
abandons 0 V
abducted 0 V
abduction 0 N
abound
abounds
abundance
abundant
accessable
```

Here is an `awk` solution

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1 in a{delete a[$1]}1; END{for(k in a) print k}' file2 file1 | 
  sort
```